# Extract data from site loaded dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am making new web scraping app to look for a job for me. I have problem with justjoin.it site which loads job offers dynamically when slider is moved. So I have a question, do I have to use for example selenium module for moving slider remotely or maybe is possible to get file from where jobs offers are loaded or any other, nicer opportunity.

To that time I only used requests and BeatifulSoup modules in Python3 to **scrape** websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it differently. If you check the requests that are made upon loading of the page (https://justjoin.it/), you will discover that there is one responsible for getting all of the offers: https://justjoin.it/api/offers.

In response, it returns all offers in JSON. You could **scrape** the needed information from it.
[image]

Comment: How did you know there is something like /api/offers. Where did you find it? I never used API.

Comment: OK I found it, thanks very much for help.